# Compute Moore-Penrose Pseudoinverse of a 3x3 matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Given a 3x3 matrix A= \begin{pmatrix}
> 1 & 1 & 1\\ 
> 1 & 1 &1 \\ 
> 1 & 1 & 1
> \end{pmatrix} Find Psuedoinverse of the above matrix

For the above matrix I am getting it as singular.
Also the rank of the above matrix is 1 so tried to calculate left and right inverse of A but am getting stuck at calculating them as they are coming out to be singular.
Does the psuedoinverse of the matrix exists or the procedure followed to find it is incorrect.

Comment: Inverses of singular matrices _do not exist_. Ever. So it's not strange that you get stuck trying to calculate one. Psuedoinverses (and particularly the Moore-Penrose one) always exist.

Comment: @Arthur I am trying to calculate left inverse $$(A^{T}A)^{-1} * A^{T} $$ but am getting a singular valued matrix as input for inverse and the rank of matrix is 1 after reducing it to row-echleon form

Comment: That formula is only valid when $A$ has full column rank, as otherwise $A^TA$ is not invertible. This $A$ obviously doesn’t.

Comment: @amd Thanks got it.Can we use SVD decomposition of the matrix to calculate Moore-Penrose Psuedo-inverse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that, if $A$ is the given matrix, then $A^2 = 3A$, and $A^3 = 9A$. Also, $A$ is symmetric. From this information, I claim that $B = \frac{1}{9}A$ is the pseudoinverse of $A$. Note that
\begin{align*}
ABA &= \frac{1}{9}A^3 = A \\
BAB &= \frac{1}{9^2}A^3 = \frac{1}{9}A = B \\
AB &= \frac{1}{3}A \\
BA &= \frac{1}{3}A,
\end{align*}
where $\frac{1}{3} A$ is symmetric. Hence, $B$ is the pseudoinverse of $A$.

Comment: How is $$ {A}^{2}=3A and {A}^{3}=9A$$.

Comment: Multiply $A$ with $A$. You're taking dot products of the vector $(1, 1, 1)$ with itself for every entry, so the result is going to be $3$s in every entry, which is $3A$. Then, $A^3 = (A^2)A = (3A)A = 3A^2 = 9A$.

Comment: Ok got it thanks